# Unexpected behavior using threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a function, that I would like to optimize through multi threading. Insted of invoking the function `RenderBodies`with the entire vector of `Body` objects in `pBodies`, as I did like this:

```
RenderBodies(pBodies);
```

I would like to call it 4 times, each time with a different quarter of the `pBodies` vector, and run them in parallel.

So I split the vectors like this:

```
std::vector<Body*> Bodies1, Bodies2, Bodies3, Bodies4;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pBodies.size(); i += 4)
{
    Bodies1.push_back(pBodies[i]);
    Bodies2.push_back(pBodies[i + 1]);
    Bodies3.push_back(pBodies[i + 2]);
    Bodies4.push_back(pBodies[i + 3]);
}
```

And then use the threads with the new vectors,

```
std::thread t1(RenderBodies, pTarget, Bodies1, pZoom);
std::thread t2(RenderBodies, pTarget, Bodies2, pZoom);
std::thread t3(RenderBodies, pTarget, Bodies3, pZoom);
std::thread t4(RenderBodies, pTarget, Bodies4, pZoom);

t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
t4.join();
```

But the result is nothing being rendered.

The thing is, there is nothing wrong with the RenderBodies function, becuase if I insted use this:

```
RenderBodies(pTarget, Bodies1, pZoom);
RenderBodies(pTarget, Bodies2, pZoom);
RenderBodies(pTarget, Bodies3, pZoom);
RenderBodies(pTarget, Bodies4, pZoom);
```

It works! But Its not using all 4 cores of my cpu so its useless.

Why would the threads not be working as expected?

My Code inside RenderBodies():

```
sf::RectangleShape Temp;

    mtx.lock();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < param.pBodies.size(); i++)
    {
        if (param.pZoom > 1)
            Temp.setSize(sf::Vector2f(param.pBodies.at(i)->mass * param.pZoom, param.pBodies.at(i)->mass * param.pZoom));
        else
            Temp.setSize(sf::Vector2f(param.pBodies.at(i)->mass, param.pBodies.at(i)->mass));

        float AccelCoefficient = static_cast<float> (sqrt(param.pBodies.at(i)->AccelX * param.pBodies.at(i)->AccelX + param.pBodies.at(i)->AccelY * param.pBodies.at(i)->AccelY) * (20000 * _GRAV_CONST));

        if (AccelCoefficient > 1)
            AccelCoefficient = 1;

        float Red, Green, Blue;

        Blue = 1 - (AccelCoefficient);

        if (AccelCoefficient < 0.2)
            Red = (AccelCoefficient)* 5;
        else
            Red = 1;

        if (AccelCoefficient < 0.5)
            Green = (AccelCoefficient)* 2;
        else
            Green = 1;

        Temp.setFillColor(sf::Color(static_cast<sf::Uint8> (Red * 255), static_cast<sf::Uint8> (Green * 255), static_cast<sf::Uint8> (Blue * 255), 128));

        Temp.setPosition(static_cast<float>(param.pBodies.at(i)->posX), (static_cast<float>(param.pBodies.at(i)->posY)));

        param.pTarget->draw(Temp);
    }
    mtx.unlock()
```

Comment: Perhaps the function `RenderBodies` is not re-entrant, causing unexpected  side effects?

Comment: What does re-entrant mean?

Comment: Not related to the problem you're asking about, but you're copying the vectors into the threads, do you really want to do that? It means you end up with 9 vectors and 3 copies of every element (which are only pointers so cheap to copy, but still ...). You could use `std::move(Bodies1)` or `std::ref(Bodies1)` to avoid copying. If you change `RenderBodies` to accept a vector and a start index and an end index then each thread could operate on the original `pBodies` vector with no additional vectors or copying needed.

Comment: A non re-entrant function may include usage of a global variable, and if not synchronized between the threads, may cause all sorts of problems.   For example, think what happens if multiple threads try to update a global variable by running   `a=a+1`.   Imagine that all threads read the value of a together, add 1 in a register and then write to memory.  Instead of increment of 4, you would get increment of 1.   This is just a simple example

Comment: @JonathanWakely The functions take a reference to a vector of node pointers, so its not coppied over

Comment: More generally (since reentrancy can also mean something in single-threaded contexts) the `RenderBodies` function is probably just not safe to call concurrently from multiple threads. This will be true if it accesses any global state or shared data, such as whatever context you are rendering into, which is likely to be the same in all threads. To call a function from multiple threads the function must not modify anything except its arguments and its own local variables unless it uses some form of synchronisation (such as a mutex or other lock, or atomic operations).

Comment: @KierenPearson, wrong, all arguments to `std::thread` get copied, and then the function is called with a reference to the _copy_. To avoid this either use `std::move` (to move instead of copying) or `std::ref` (to use a `reference_wrapper` which acts like a reference) as I said. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread#Notes

Comment: @JonathanWakely, I'm a bit confused of the syntax, so is it ment to be `std::thread t1(RenderBodies, pTarget, std::move(Bodies1), pZoom);`?

Comment: By creating thread, you are not creating thread for specific core, you just create threads to run simultaneously, C++ does not know about cores..

Comment: Could, inside RenderBodies, calling one of pTarget's (its pointer to a object) member functions (`ptarget->draw( .... )`) be causing this issue?

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use threads.”   two Now have problems they.](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: @KierenPearson, yes, that's the right syntax. And yes, that call to `draw` is almost certainly the problem. How can multiple threads can all draw at the same time, if that means modifying the same rendering context simultaneously?

Comment: As Photon wrote, RenderBodies is probably not re-entrant. Try to sleep for one second (or few seconds) between each thread initialisation and see what happens. If it works, RenderBodies is most probably not re-entrant.

Comment: Ok so we have tracked down the issue to the draw function, how can I fix this now? Is there some way to make the threads access it one at a time?

Comment: @KierenPearson, don't assume that's the **only** problem. Since you haven't shown any of the relevant code there could be other problems. To make them access one at a time you use a mutex, accessible by all threads, and lock it before calling `draw` and unlock it after. But if most of the work in `RenderBodies` happens in the draw function then all you've done is make the program single-threaded again. Read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law

Comment: @KierenPearson, you will probably not get anything with multithreading drawing. Either draw with only one thread, or consider GPU drawing library like OpenGL, which does paralelisation on GPU.

Comment: As the name of the function is *RenderBodies*, I assume it could be GUI rendering. And many GUI systems require that all GUI accesses come from the thread that initialized  the initial GUI access.

Comment: Incidentally, as you want to "improve performance", copying your entire input set seems like a bad idea. Why not pass iterator ranges instead? Granted, now your segmentation is different (you wouldn't get ABCDABCD any more but AABBCCDD) but, assuming that's okay, you can now segment your data completely trivially just by telling the function "start here and end here, in the original data".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, already suggested above, 3rd comment :) The segmentation can be preserved by using a stride of 4 if necessary.

Comment: Are you rendering with OpenGL? If so, each thread has its own context, and a context can only be associated with one thread at a time.

Comment: I am rendering with SFML

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what the `RenderBodies()` function is doing, it's not possible to give a precise answer.

However, my guess is that it is related to the argument `pTarget` for which the same value is being passed to all the threads and (from the name) is a pointer.   If so, that means you have four threads interacting with one object - so it is necessary for the threads to synchronise their access to that object (e.g. using a mutex or critical section).

If the threads aren't doing much other than rendering to `pTarget`, synchoronising access to it will negate most of the benefits of multithreading (since, effectively, that causes all the threads to wait on each other and all the rendering is again sequential).

However, that's the way it goes.   Multithreading is not a free lunch.  The way to get performance is to minimise synchronisation between threads (i.e. making them wait for each other).   If you don't do that, you get race conditions, so operations may not complete correctly - which is what you seem to be describing.

That's why one guideline of user interface design is often that only one thread is responsible for rendering a window/screen.

Comment: You might want to mention [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law)

Comment: Yes. Reading through the comments above, it seems the issue is a call to one of the member functions of the object pointed to by pTarget, and having this function be called from multiple threads. What is the fix for this?

Comment: This answer already tells you the fix: "so it is necessary for the threads to synchronise their access to that object (e.g. using a mutex or critical section)." But are you sure you really want to use threads here? It seems like you're just hoping to sprinkle magic multithreaded pixie dust and get faster code, it's not that easy.

Comment: Jonathan:  Amdahl's law is not the issue here, since the concern is invalid interaction between threads, not a performance limitation.   Kieren:  as I said, the solution is either to synchronise access (e.g. wrap the call of the offending member function of `pTarget` in a mutex, so only one thread calls it at a time) and accept the performance hit, or do without multithreading (which is often the better idea for actions such as rendering to screens).

Comment: @Peter, As you yourself said _"synchoronising access to it will negate most of the benefits of multithreading (since, effectively, that causes all the threads to wait on each other and all the rendering is again sequential)."_ ... how is Amdahl's Law not relevant here?

Comment: I tried using a mutex, but it didn't do anything. I put the lock and unlock at the very top and bottom of the function too @Jonathan Wakely

Comment: @KierenPearson, until you show the code for `RenderBodies` any further discussion is a waste of time, as noone has any idea what your code does, how you're using a mutex etc. "I changed something, it still doesn't work" is useless information.

Comment: Jonathan:  Because the limit on performance gain (which is what Amdahl's law describes) is a side issue - the actual issue in the question is correctness of execution.